# Check if user is online in realtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I want to check if a User is online at this moment. This should be shown on the users profile.

I got this in my `application_controller`

```
after_filter :user_activity

private

  def user_activity
    current_user.try :touch
  end
```

I defined this in the `user-model`

```
def online?
 updated_at > 10.minutes.ago
end
```

I can check in the view if the user is online: (HAML)

```
- if @user.online?
```

This works, but there is always a reload of the page required to update this information.
How can it made into a realtimecheck?
Maybe using ActionCable?

PS: using `devise`

Comment: you could also use javascript `setInterval` http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp, and make an ajax request to check if the user is online in the function you pass to `setInterval`

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Action Cable can be used for this. The Rails guide has (half of) an example of this here: [Action Cable Overview -- 6.1 Example 1: User Appearance](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html#example-1-user-appearances%20*Action%20Cable%20Overview%20%7C%206.1.%20Example%201:%20User%20Appearances*)

Basically, you create an `AppearanceChannel` and every user is subscribed to it. Subscribing calls the `appear` function for the `current_user`, which can then be broadcast out (e.g., to show online status to other users), typically via a background job like `BroadcastAppearanceJob`.
(I have just started working through this myself).

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this would be using your client-side technology. The server can only know if a user has been active based on their last request to the server.

The user may be browsing around your app without a request being sent to the server, and would show as not online based on your time limit (even though they are active).

Consider using websockets to accomplish this whether it's in JavaScript, Obj-C/Swift, or Java.

Comment: Can you suggest any resources, where I can get mor information concerning this?

Comment: Socket.io, Pusher

Answer (score 2):

I tried with the Action Cable example but i had some issues (.disappear is not called when I reboot the server, also hard to handle when the user open multiple tabs etc...)

So the simplest working solution would be a way to call the server every 5 minutes, like this in javascript :

```
setInterval(function(){
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("GET", "/i_am_still_here", true);
  xhttp.send();
}, 5*60*1000);
```

and so in the controller

```
def i_am_still_here
  current_user.update(last_seen_at:DateTime.now)
end
```

and so in User.rb

```
def is_online?
  last_seen_at > 5.minutes.ago
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as Noah wrote, client-side is a natural choice for this. The client can at a selected interval initiate a database update indicating that they are present. Detecting the presence of another user involves checking if their update is fresh enough.

A page load seems mandatory, but with ajax it does not use much resources. You could (and should) even create a special layout for the ajax target page, without extra burden like css and js.

I use this javascript in a view (dependency: jquery):

```
function update_presence() {
  $.ajax({
    url:  '/presence',
    // data: { "my_get_param": "whatever" },
    type: 'GET'
    })
    .done(function(response){
      $('div#last-seen').html(response);
    })
}
// run it every 30 seconds
setInterval(update_presence, 30000)
```

Then define a route, action and view, just as normally. In my `presence` action in the controller I have a call to the helper function:

```
update_presence(current_user)
```

The helper function is an oneliner:

```
def update_presence(user)
  user.update_attribute(:last_seen, DateTime.now)
end
```

In the view you can display some result that you may need. My javascript (see above) displays the result on the page, but that is only for testing.

```
<%= current_user.last_seen %>
```

In the model I have a method to check presence:

```
def is_present?
  self.last_seen  > 2.minutes.ago
end
```

So for any user you can call `@user.is_present?`. But to update the presence indicators dynamically on a webpage, I think another ajax call is needed.